# What is the proper sequence for the GTA Online heists?

Tags: grand-theft-auto-online

I want to play those heist preparation missions but always get the message, that I lose the bonus if I interrupt the sequence.

So what is the correct sequence in which I have to play them? (I don't own a high class property so I cannot start them by myself.)

I am playing on the PS3.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

### 1. Fleeca Job

A introductory heist for 2 players involving stealing bonds from a safety deposit box from the Great Ocean Highway Fleeca Bank for Lester Crest and using a Kuruma to escape before a Cargobob airlifts the car to evade the police.

**Setup missions are:**

- Scope Out the bank and delivering a Granger full of equipment to the 
  Heist Leader's garage.
- Kuruma - steal the car from the Khangpae in a Del Perro parking
  garage.

### 2. Prison Break

The second heist, and the first requiring a full crew of four players, involves a complicated plan to spring a prisoner from Bolingbroke Penitentiary.

**Setup missions are:**

- Plane - steal a Velum from the Vagos at McKenzie Field Hangar.
- Bus - obtain a Prison Bus.
- Station - One team steal the inmate transfer schedule from the
  Mission Row Police Station, while the other team obtains the Casco
  from the docks.
- Wet Work - One team kills Rashkovsky's former business partner and
  the other team kills two lawyers and recovers a briefcase.

### 3. Humane Raid

A heist involving raiding Humane Labs and Research, similar to the single player mission Monkey Business.

**Setup missions are:**

- Key Codes - obtain access codes to the lab from IAA Agent Karen while holding off the FIB.
- Insurgents - obtain Insurgents from a Merryweather test site in Davis Quartz.
- EMP - steal fighter jets from an Aircraft Carrier, one fitted with an EMP device.
- Valkyrie - steal a Valkyrie from Merryweather at the Los Santos Naval Port.
- Deliver EMP - deliver the EMP to the research lab in the unarmed Insurgent.

### 4. Series A

A heist involving collecting various drug packages for Trevor and then helping Trevor deliver them to his drug deal at the El Gordo Lighthouse.

**Setup missions are:**

- Coke - steal coke from dealers on a yacht near Del Perro.
- Trash Truck - steal a Trashmaster and collect molly pills in trash bags from the Vagos.
- Bikers - infiltrate the Lost MC camp at night then stealing their vans.
- Weed - steal a shipment of weed and a technical truck from the Ballas at the Paleto Forest Sawmill.
- Steal Meth - steal the ingredients from the O'Neil Brothers at the farm.

### 5. Pacific Standard

The final heist involving robbing the Pacific Standard Bank.

**Setup missions are:**

- Vans - take pictures of Post OP trucks, then steal the right one.
- Signal - Bring a transponder to Avi Schwartzman, so he can tune it to the right frequency for the Pacific Standard dye packs.
- Hack - steal data from a black Declasse Gang Burrito.
- Convoy - Hijack a Merryweather convoy to get thermal charges (to use on the security doors at the Pacific Standard).
- Bikes - steal four Lectros from the Lost MC at their East Los Santos camp to use as your escape vehicle.

[Source](http://gta.wikia.com/Heists_Update)

Comment: I'm not 100% sure if you have to do setup missions in order, but if you do, they are in the right order in my answer.

Comment: You have to do some in order and some not. Usually you have to start from first one, but for example in Humane Raid, second and third unlocks at the same moment and you can start doing from any of them.

Comment: What about the Diamond Casino Heist???

Comment: @Jonathan It is separate from these heists. These are apartment heists, they can only be started if the heist leader has a high-end apartment. Diamond Casino heists require the heist leader to have an arcade.